# RHEL/CentOS: Installing a new version of Java, why not just change the path?

Tags: package-management, centos, rpm, development, java

I am installing a new version of Java on a CentOS/RHEL Linux distro for a single developer to develop java.

The way I want to install on this development system is to just put the new java version somewhere and then update my path so that the new java is earlier on the path (and thus executes always) instead of the old version of java (which will be later on the path).

But while looking online I came across an official multi-page howto for this distro... and it describes a completely different idea of what I SHOULD do: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaOnCentOS

**For a single developer, is modifying the path (to point to the new java) going to work for developing java?**

**Why would you ever want to go through the laborious description seen on the above referenced official wiki page?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing Java is easy, just dump the jdk to /usr/local or /opt and then modify your `PATH` as you said. Personally, I would remove the old java path entirely, but that's me. I usually put it in /usr/local and then symlink it to a generic name, like simply **jdk** or similar, that way when I upgrade it I don't have to change anything that depends on the package. I only need to delete the symlink and recreate it to point to the new version.

I suspect you'll have other environment variables you'll need to modify in order for development to move forward. `JAVA_LIB` is a common environment variable, which would be set to the lib directory under the jdk, naturally.

Also, you said in your post "update *my* path", did you mean your personal `PATH` variable or did you mean the system wide settings ?? I only ask because if you modify *your* path the developer will not pick up the change in *his* `PATH`, if you're using separate logins.

As to the question of why anyone would follow that wiki page, I would hope no one would. It's 4 years old and hasn't been maintained since then according to the page.

All that being said, I'm sure that java is provided by your package manager (yum or what have you) and I would suggest that you go that route and let the system handle the installation for you if it can be done.

Comment: yum for centOS gets an older java... i want latest/greatest. hence manually getting latest java and doing what I am doing.